# nodejs ejs render array object in to table

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Good day
I need to write a table from a database and i can't access the values, if the array is greater than 1...
If i do it like this:

```
    //spielzeiten
   var spielzeitenArr = [{
        spzeit: "",
        spielzeit_id: "",
    }];
    var spzeitData = await myDB.selectSpielzeit();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1/*spzeitData.length*/; i++) {
        spielzeitenArr[i].spzeit = "meine Zeit" /*spzeitData.spzeit*/;
        spielzeitenArr[i].spielzeit_id = "meine ID"/*spzeitData.spielzeit_id*/;
    }

        res.render('index', {
            firmen: firmanameArr,
            block: blocknameArr,
            datei: dateinameArr,
            jinglein: jingleinArr,
            jingleout: jingleoutArr,
            szdata: spielzeitenArr
        });
```

and on the ejs side it looks like this:

```
        <table id="todoTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="tdList">Datum</td>
                <td class="tdList">Zeit</td>
                <td class="tdList">Start Jingle</td>
                <td class="tdList">End Jingle</td>
                <td class="tdList">Name</td>
                <td class="tdList">
                    <div class="select-wrapper">
                        <select id="categoryFilter" class="selectCompany"></select>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <% szdata.forEach((item) => { %>
            <tr></tr>
            <td><%= item.spzeit %></td>
            <td><%= item.spielzeit_id %></td>
            <% }); %>
        </table>
```

if i use my hardcoded value, it works. But if i try to change the i value to 2 or more, it gives me an error... why is this so?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: You can answer this yourself by using ```console.log(`data length: ${spzeitData.length}`)``` before your for loop, and looking at the console output. You're almost certainly going to see `data length: 0` and if you expected a different value, start debugging `myDB.selectSpielzeit()` to see why it's giving you an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your `spielzeiten` array with a length of 1 and not increasing its size if you have more than one record. Thus, of course if you try to access an `spielzeiten[i].spzeit` with an index different from 0 you get an error.

You should probably initialize your array as an empty array and add new items during the loop.

```
spielzeiten = [];

for (let i = 0; i < spzeitData.length; i++) {
  spielzeiten.push({
    spzeit: spzeitData[i].spzeit,
    id: spzeitData[i].spielzeit_id
  });
}
```

You could also use the `Array.map` function to directly initialize your array

```
let spielzeiten = spzeitData.map(d => ({ 
  spzeit: d.spzeit, 
  id: d.spielzeit_id
}));
```